# Returning React component where props and state are mixed together

Tags: javascript, data-structures, reactjs

I think this may be an anti-pattern, but I want to use props and state together in defining the class names for a component. That way, I can assign multiple classes.

My pattern is:

```
render: function() {
    return (
    <div className="portrait-speaker default" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <audio className={this.props.defaultclass} + {this.state.playingclass} ref="player" preload={this.props.preload}>
            <source src={this.props.src} type={this.props.mimeType} />
        </audio>
    </div>
    );
}
```

This obviously is not working. What is the best way to use `props` and `state` together to mix immutable and mutable data types within `className`?

Comment: It's not an anti-pattern. To make this more readable you can try using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with "mixing" state and props to generate css classes, but you might have been getting a syntax error because of this :

`className={this.props.defaultclass} + {this.state.playingclass}`

React only evaluates js within curly brackets here, so the "+" could be breaking something. See this fix:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="portrait-speaker default" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <audio className={this.props.defaultclass + ' ' + this.state.playingclass} ref="player" preload={this.props.preload}>
                <source src={this.props.src} type={this.props.mimeType} />
            </audio>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Mixing indeed does seem like the wrong term for this. How would we describe it? Not quite a mixin, not a concat.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally an anti-pattern to store a className in state. Instead store the minimal data that can be used to determine the className in render.

Also `classnames` is a tiny library that merges classNames and allow conditional names. It's very handy.

```
var classnames = require('classnames')

// ...

  <audio 
    className={classnames(this.props.defaultclass, {
      /* only has 'is-playing' class when this.state.playing is `true` */
      'is-playing': this.state.playing,
    })} 
    ref="player" 
    preload={this.props.preload}
  >
```